# Set element's innerHTML to random string

Tags: javascript, html, hash

I need to make `hash-paragraph`'s `.innerHTML` to random string with JavaScript.

I've tried this:

```js
function CreateHash() {
  var randomhash = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
  randomhash.id = "randomhash";
  document.getElementById("hash-paragraph").innerHTML = document.getElementById("randomhash").value;
}
```

```html
<p id="hash-paragraph">This should be random string</p>
<input type="submit" name="hash-click" onclick="CreateHash()">
```

Am i missing some rows or `var randomhash = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');` is a wrong way to go?

Comment: Which type of element is the one with id `randomhash` ? an input? because `getElementById()` is used only for get elements from DOM, if you simply want to set the value from variable `randomhash`, not element with that id, then just do `... = randomhash;`

Comment: there is no element in html randomhash. I thought I can make one in script that will just be used to set paragraph's ````innerHTML```` to it's value ( random string - hash )

Comment: Sorry. I've tried with ````document.getElementById("hash-paragraph").innerHTML = randomhash;````. I've used ````.getElementById```` because I have previously set randomhash's id to ````randomhash.id = "randomhash";````

Comment: yes, it was a typo. Did try with hash-paragraph, but it is blank when I reload a page

Comment: It does rebuild everything, but when I click the ````<input>```` and run the script, it is still blank (doesn't change innerHTML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a `randomBytes` method in the Web Crypto API standard. This is a method only available on the Crypto NodeJS Module. The equivalent in this case would be `crypto.getRandomValues()`. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto) provides more information about it.

Edit: The `crypto.getRandomValues()` method, requires a TypedArray as parameter to feed it with the entropy values. I attach a [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/geekzolanos-dev/pen/mdJOOdo) showing how generate it and convert the result to a hex format suitable for your needs.

Comment: but what if asker is using: [crypto.randombytes()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) ?

Comment: Yeap, maybe is NodeJS refered. But there's not any reference to the platform in the question. Also it haves some HTML on the example, providing a web development context.

Comment: Yes, I need it for a website. I need when clicked a button to make random string ( hash ) that will later be stored in mySQL

Comment: I've tried with ````var randomhash = crypto.getRandomValues(20);```` and later ````document.getElementById("hash").innerHTML = randomhash;```` , but not working

Comment: Did you have an element with id `hash` ?

Comment: yes, but it's 'hash-paragraph', my bad. ````<p id="hash-paragraph"></p>````

Comment: Technically you're not looking for a "Hash", because don't need generate a checksum of some existing content, instead, you need some entropy source to generate random values with a fixed length. I'll update the answer with a Codepen example showing how do this.

Comment: `[...crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(20))].map(m => ('0' + m.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('')`